# Why does the future package does not find a function?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, future

I am implementing parallelization using function parLapply from package parallel. This package requires exporting objects using the function clusterExport(). After watching a video about the package future I thought I could avoid the export step by using it. It has not worked, as the example below will demonstrate.

Here is the code:

```
library("future")

source("C:\\Dropbox\\Code\\R\\TestFuncs.R")

plan(sequential)
plan(multisession, workers=4)
bas <- function(x) {sapply(1:10, bas2(x))}

bar <- function(y) {bas(y)}

foo <- function(x) {bar(x)}

test <- lapply(1:100, function(x) future({ foo(x) }))
testvals <- lapply(test, value)
```

The sourced file TestFuncs.R contains the following code:

```
bas2 <- function(y) { y+1 }
```

When I try to run the program above I get the following message in RStudio:

```
> testvals <- lapply(test, value)
Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
    'bas2(x)' is not a function, character or symbol

Called from: signalConditions(future, exclude = getOption("future.relay.immediate", 
    "immediateCondition"), resignal = TRUE)

Browse[1]>
```

I checked that the function bas2 is in the global enviroment. I also checked that the same problem happens in an RGui session, with a simpler error message.

Why is this happening and how do I deal with this issue?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't seem have anything to do with future. YOur `bas` function doesn't seem to work. In it's current state

```
bas <- function(x) {sapply(1:10, bas2(x))}
```

Running it on its own gives the same error

```
bas(1)
#  Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
#   'bas2(x)' is not a function, character or symbol
```

The second parameter to `sapply` needs to be a function, not an expression. It should look like

```
bas <- function(x) {sapply(1:10, function(y) bas2(x))}
```

(Note I used `y` in the inner function because I wasn't sure what `x` you wanted to use when calling `bas2`).

Comment: You are right, but that did not solve my problem. I tried to make a reproducible example and I failed. Corrected the way you suggested the example program works. My original program still does not work. Now I realize it had a different problem. When I call value() on the result of lapply with future it gives me this message 
<Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.data.frame': object 'conjunction_func' not found>
This happens even though conjunction_func is defined in the same program file.

Comment: It’s very hard to offer any other further help without a reproducible example that results in the same error.

Comment: I know. Thanks for trying. I tried to create a reproducible example and that did not work. My program is a bit complex and I will have to try harder. In the meanwhile I found a solution. I was trying to debug and found the error was happening inside a function that I will call FUN. I put a print(conjunction_func) (without quotes) in FUN to debug and the error went away. Then I found that I do not need the print statement. Just putting 'conjunction_func' without the quotes around it or the function definition in the body of FUN solves the problem. I don't know why that works.